# How to do a performSegue to a specific view in Tab Bar Controller from another view (swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nstabviewcontroller

In my iOS app, in a **viewController** I try to open a specific view in **Tab Bar Controller**.
I use a performSegue.
First I try to navigate straight to the specific view , but in this case the **tab bar** disappear
 
So I try to navigate to the tabViewController, and this lead me to the defult view (the first)

**any idea how to navigate to a specific view in TabBarController ?**

the performSegue I use:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)
//"goToMain" is my indentipier to the storyboard Segue
```

> **I use swift 4**

Comment: this is very unclear. can you share a screenshot to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this code, you don't need segues, you can use when you push some button

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! tabBarLoginViewController
VC1.selectedIndex = 2 //this line says that the view that appears will be third of you tab bar controller
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
```

if you want to use segue use this, the segue needs to point of tab bar controller, not a view of tab bar controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToMain") {
    let vc = segue.destination as! TabBarController
    vc.selectedIndex = 2 
    }
}
```